# Routing not working in a new window for deployed project

Tags: angular, build, angular2-routing, new-window

Currently working on a project where a component has to be opened in a new browser window to display some data.

When we run the code locally, as well as when doing a build with simple parameters, the tab seems to load just fine, and we can view the data required. But whenever we run the code off of our release build parameters, the new window seems to become completely disconnected from the code, not even the base HTML loading in.

The parameters for the local build that works are as follows:

```json
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"buildOptimizer": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"optimization": false,
"namedChunks": true
```

The parameters for the release build are as follows

```json
"fileReplacements":  [
  {
    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts"
    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
],
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
     "minify": true,
     "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": {
    "inline": true
  }
},
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"namedChunks": false,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
"baseHref": ".",
"budgets": [
  {
    "type": "initial",
    "maximumWarning": "10mb",
    "maximumError": "20mb"
  },
  {
    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
    "maximumWarning": "6kb"
  }
]
```

Any ideas on which parameters on the release build might be causing the routing to lose the codebase?

Comment: Routing to lose the codebase? It is highly unlikely that your app is losing its codebase or it would not run. Where are you deploying the app? Which method are you using to open your new tab? Is the new tab opened dependent on some state you have locally?

Comment: The codebase is lost only in the new window, not on the application as a whole.

The app is being deployed on a company server via IIS Management Console. 
The new window is being opened by window.open, with the route passed as a parameter.

The new window isn't dependent on any values or state from any local machine, but the data it utilize does pass through the localStorage variable. This doesn't seem to be an issue with the basic build parameters listed above for our "local" build, even when that build is deployed on the same server as the "release" build.

Comment: Are your URLs different from one another?

Comment: The URLs for both the "local" and the "release" build are the same.

Comment: I mean between the app you are calling window.open from and the windoe.open that opens it.

Comment: The base URL is the same, but the two URLs are like the following

Main Window: "server_name:8888/main_route?RestValue1=value1&RestValue2..."
New Window: "server_name:8888/main_route/secondary_route"